# evaluate lambda calculus- OR FALSE TRUE

Tags: lambda-calculus

TRUE = λxy. x

FALSE = λxy. y

IF = λbtf. b t f

AND = λxy. IF x y FALSE

OR = λxy. IF x TRUE y

NOT = λx. IF x FALSE TRUE

How can I use lambda calculus to beta reduce the expression OR FALSE TRUE? I'm not sure where to start. My lecturer did not go through it. Here's my attempt

```
(\xy.IF x TRUE y)(\xy.y)(\xy.x)
= (\xy.IF x TRUE y)[x := (\xy.y))(\xy.x)
= (\y. IF (\xy.y) TRUE y)(\xy.x)
= (IF (\xy.y) TRUE y)[y := (\xy.x))
= IF (\xy.y) TRUE (\xy.x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working with Church-encodings I think it is best to stay as abstract as possible, i.e., you should not unfold `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `IF` and `NOT` eagerly but only when needed.

Instead you first want to prove basic results about their behaviour, this will also make for a sanity check.
For `IF` you want to check that `IF TRUE t f = t` and `IF FALSE t f = f`.

```
IF TRUE t f = TRUE t f   (IF returns its arguments directly)
            = t          (TRUE returns its first argument)
```

Same for `IF FALSE`.

Now

```
OR FALSE TRUE = IF FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

and by applying the identity you already proved you should be able to conclude.